# Show default page when Curl takes too long to connect to API

Tags: php, api, curl, timeout

I currently have a script on the homepage of a website connecting to an api service. There are occasions when the api takes too long to respond, I am trying to figure out a way to show default results if the response takes more than three seconds. I am not sure how to do this though. Here is my curl script:

```
class Ofertas{
public $Name;
public $HotelId;
public $Coordinates = array();
public $Longs;
public $Response = array();


public function __construct($var){

$ofertas = new SqlIt('SELECT destination_id, destination_name, bottom_link, link FROM **** ORDER BY slot ASC LIMIT '.$var,'select',array());

foreach($ofertas->Response as $did){
    $coor = new SqlIt("SELECT CenterLatitude, CenterLongitude, RegionName FROM ***** WHERE RegionID = ? LIMIT ".$var,"select",array($did->destination_id));
    array_push($this->Coordinates,array($coor->Response[0]->CenterLatitude,$coor->Response[0]->CenterLongitude,$coor->Response[0]->RegionName));
}
$i = 0;
$url = "http://apiurl";
$curl_arr = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();
$i = 0;
foreach($this->Coordinates as $co){
    $xml = '<xmlrequesthere>xml code goes here for request</xmlrequesthere>';

            $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml); 
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml')); 
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,1); // number of seconds to wait for initial connection
            curl_setopt(curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2); //timeout for entire process.
            curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);



        do {
            curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
        } while($running > 0);

        if (curl_errno($curl_arr[$i])) {
                //fetch default hotels from the database

        }else{

            $results = curl_multi_getcontent  ( $curl_arr[$i]  );
            $apit = simplexml_load_string($results);
            $j['destination'] = $ofertas->Response[$i]->destination_name;
            $j['button'] = $ofertas->Response[$i]->bottom_link;
            $j['link'] = $ofertas->Response[$i]->link;
            $j['hotels'] = array();
            foreach($apit->HotelList->HotelSummary as $res){
                $hh['name'] = $res->name.'';
                $hh['hid'] = $res->hotelId.'';
                $hh['city'] = $res->city.'';
                $hh['rate'] = $res->lowRate.'';
                $hh['thumb'] = $res->thumbNailUrl.'';

                array_push($j['hotels'],$hh);
            }
        }

    array_push($this->Response, $j); 
$i++; }

    }
}//end of class
```

Should I be closing the connection somewhere? Or I just want to add a timeout like I said.. ANY HELP would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a example of the 2 timeout flags that you could use to cause curl to return if the process is taking to long.

```
curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,1); // number of seconds to wait for initial connection
curl_setopt(curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2); //timeout for entire process.
```

You dont need to close the connection anywhere because libcurl will simply be calling the 'curl' process via exec() or a similar function for you and that will handle all socket IO.

Once the timeout has occurred you can check to see if a error occurred with:

```
if (curl_errno($curl_arr[$i])) {
    // Error Handling code here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you Damian, quick question.. where would it return to? How would I be able to maybe do a php action when it times out? Or should I redirect it? This is where I am most confused. Thank you sooooo much!

Comment: I have amended my answer to include more detail so you can perform appropriate error handling when a timeout (or any other error) occurs.

Comment: Should I add this inside the do{ or outside? Thank you again for helping!

Comment: Well this would depend on your logic, you did not provide enough of a code snippet to show where $i is incremented. You should call it individually on each curl handle object.. One possible issue that I can see here is that you are repeating calls in your for loop (so each call to curl_multi_exec is adding one more call to the multi-curl-handle.

Comment: I am adding it after the curl_multi_exec. How would I correct this? You have officially become my savior!!

Comment: I'm actually not sure , you would need to provide a slightly larger code sample for me to see properly, but as a general rule you could first setup your arrays and add all the handles to master and then call multi exec outside of that specific loop. ( and then maybe have another loop at the bottom to process/parse results )

Comment: I have provided the entire php class and db functions above. Let me know if this helps. THANK YOU again and again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72893/discussion-between-damian-nikodem-and-whitney-sarah-rogers).